# Can't get code to write to text file in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

I am was tasked with commanding a multimeter from my computer using python and storing the information into a text file. I have tried altering the code in a million ways and I can not figure out what I am doing wrong. The file already exists in my computer but nothing ever gets displayed there.

```
import serial
import time
import math
import string

#setting up connection to Multimeter through COM6
ser = serial.Serial('COM6')
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stopbites = 1
ser.timeout = 1

class testing():
    def test():

        #getting user input
        serialNum = input("Serial number: ")
        date = input("Date: ")
        time = input("Time: ")

        x = 1
        if x==1:
            ser.write(b'meas:volt:dc?\r\n')
            returnBytes = ser.readline()
            fbytes = float(returnBytes)
            #print("DC voltage: " + returnBytes)
            ser.close()
            return fbytes

            
        #saving and printing information to text file
        lines = [serialNum, date, time, fbytes]
        file = open('/Users/myname/test.txt', 'w')
        file.write(''.join(lines))
        file.close()
```

Comment: Is this all the code? You don't create a `testing` object and never call the `test` function.

Comment: When you set `x = 1`, and then check if `x == 1`, you `return` from the function, so you never get to the part of the code that writes to the file.

Comment: yes this is all the code, i can run the code and get a reading from the multimeter, but none of the information saves to the file and i dont know how to fix it

Comment: In python, you don't need the `class testing() def test()` that you need in arduino/java. remove those two lines, and de-indent everything

Comment: Also remove the line `return fbytes`.

Comment: I think I figured it out, I plan on having much more code for various functions related to the multimeter so I was starting with just one. Thanks everyone!

Comment: If you have figured bit out, please post your code as an answer so everybody can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem i posted about, however the code is still spitting out an error that I am trying to solve. but for the sake of the question, this is what i revised my code to so that the information would display in the text file

```
import serial
import time
import math
import string

#setting up connection to Multimeter through COM6
ser = serial.Serial('COM6')
ser.baudrate = 9600
ser.bytesize = 8
ser.parity = 'N'
ser.stopbites = 1
ser.timeout = 1

#getting user input
serialNum = str(input("Serial number: "))
date = str(input("Date: "))
time = str(input("Time: "))

#getting measurement of DC voltage
ser.write(b'meas:volt:dc?\n')         #'b' encodes info from meter to bytes
returnDC = ser.readline()
fbytesDC = float(returnDC)

#getting resistance measurement
ser.write(b'meas:res?\n')             #'b' encodes info from meter to bytes
returnRes = ser.readline()
fbytesRes = float(returnRes)

#close the active port
ser.close()
                    
#saving and printing information to text file
lines = [serialNum, date, time]
file = open("C:/Users/myname/test.txt", "a+")
file.write(' '.join(lines))
file.write(" DC voltage: "+ str(fbytesDC))
file.write(" Resistance: "+ str(fbytesRes))
file.write("\n")
file.close()
```